# How access a VM console in XCP?

Tags: ubuntu, xen

I installed xcp-xapi package in Ubuntu 12.10. I have already created a PV VM in XenCenter, but I cannot access it's console -- when I choose the Console tab in XenCenter, I just got a blank page.

I tried this via console and got this:

```
bear@ubuntu-tmp1:~$ sudo xe vm-list params=dom-id
dom-id ( RO)    : 0


dom-id ( RO)    : 2


bear@ubuntu-tmp1:~$ sudo xenstore-ls /local/domain/2/serial
0 = ""
 limit = "65536"
bear@ubuntu-tmp1:~$
```

According this official [link](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Xen_Cloud_Platform:_Access_to_VM_console), I should at least see 'tty' and 'vnc' in output, but I got neither of them...
Now I completely have no way to install OS on that VM because there is no console available... :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a hidden CLI command (for which I have submitted a request to make non-hidden):

```
xe console uuid=<vm_uuid>
```

Note that this only works for PV guests. Alternatively, for both PV and HVM guests, you can use vncviewer to get a VNC console. Use xenstore to get the VNC port:

```
PORT=xenstore-read /local/domain/${domid}/console/vnc-port
```

and then call:

```
vncviewer -via root@${YOUR_SERVER} localhost::${PORT}
```

Here is a script which does this for you:

```
#!/bin/bash

function usage () {
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "   `basename $0` -h <xenserver host> -g <guest vm name-label>"
    echo "   `basename $0` -h <xenserver host> -u <guest vm uuid>"
    echo "   `basename $0` -h <xenserver host> -d <domID>"
    exit 1
}

while getopts "h:g:u:d:" option
do
    case $option in
        h ) xs=${OPTARG} ;;
        g ) vm=${OPTARG} ;;
        u ) uu=${OPTARG} ;;
        d ) id=${OPTARG} ;;
        * ) usage
    esac
done

if [ -z ${xs} ]; then
    usage
fi

if [ -z ${uu} ] && [ -z ${vm} ] && [ -z ${id} ]; then
    usage
fi

if [ ! -z ${uu} ]; then
    domid=`ssh root@${xs} xe vm-list uuid=${uu} params=dom-id --minimal`
elif [ ! -z ${vm} ]; then
    domid=`ssh root@${xs} xe vm-list name-label=${vm} params=dom-id --minimal`
elif [ ! -z ${id} ]; then
    domid=${id}
fi

if [ -z ${domid} ]; then
    echo "Could not find guest ${vm}${uu} on host ${xs}."
    exit 1
elif [ ${domid} -lt 0 ]; then
    echo "Guest ${vm}${uu} has no dom-id. Is your vm running?"
    exit 1
fi

port=`ssh root@${xs} xenstore-read /local/domain/${domid}/console/vnc-port`

if [ -z ${port} ]; then
    echo "Couldn't read VNC port from xenstore. Is your vm running?"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Connecting to vnc port ${port} on host ${xs}..."
set -x
vncviewer -via root@${xs} localhost::${port}
```